# Time Complexity Analysis in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, time, time-complexity, big-o

Hi there I have been researching and trying to learn how to check for the time complexity of certain algorithms. I've seen this video which was very helpful.

That being said I wondered off and started trying to work out the Worsts Case and an average case of certain algorithms.

## 1

```
function sqrt(num) {
guess = num / 3;

  do {
    lastGuess = guess; 


    guess = (num / guess + guess) / 2;

   while(Math.abs(lastGuess - guess));

  return guess;  /
```

Am I correct to say this is O(n) my reasoning is since we loop until an approx is found.

## 2

```
function max(numArray) 
{
    // copy the given array 
    nums = numArray.slice();

    // base case: if we're at the last number, return it
    if (nums.length == 1) { return nums[0]; }

    // check the first two numbers in the array and remove the lesser
    if (nums[0] < nums[1]) { nums.splice(0,1); }
    else { nums.splice(1,1); }

    // with one less number in the array, call the same function
    return max(nums);
}
```

From the user thanks in the link, he calculates the largest number in an array. Is it safe to say that the time complexity in this is `O(n)` since the largest number may be at the very last, and hence why `O(n)`?

**#3**
While I believe in the following snippet it is O(n) since to ind the value for sin we have to loop the entire array.

```
function mySin(x, iterNum) {
    var mxx = -x*x;
    var sin = 1;
    var n = 0;
    var term = 1;
    for (var i = 1; i <= 2*iterNum; i++) {
        n = n + 2;
        term = term * mxx / ( n*(n+1) );
        sin = sin + term
    }
    sin = x*sin;
    console.log(sin + " = my function.");
    console.log(Math.sin(x)  + " math.sin");
}
```

Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

For the second you are right: It is `O(n)` as yu need to traverse `n` elements to find the maximum. In the first case however, ypu dont have anything that changes in your input. It will always take a few steps until you hit the guess, that is somehow independent of the size of the number you pass in. Therefore it is rather `O(1)`. For example these numbers all only have one digit, but the algorithm takes a different number of iterations for each:

```
 sqrt(9) // 1 iteration
 sqrt(3) // a few iterations
```

One could also say that we can't predict the time complexity of the first one.

Comment: Hi Jonas thanks a lot! I'm relatively new and I'm trying to practice on these. I specifically asked #1 since I couldn't find anything online regarding do...while loop. That being said in the following piece of code: for (var i = 1; i <= 2*iterNum; i++) {
        n = n + 2;
        term = term * mxx / ( n*(n+1) );
        sin = sin + term
    }
Am I correct to say that this is also O(n) since it loops until we find the answer?